# textbox value not getting another form button click event in winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on windows form application and I have two forms. 1 is visitorinfo 2 is vistorexitsign.

In the visitorinfo I have save button, while cliking save button I want to get textboxvalue from vistirexitsign form.

Both forms are running at the same time, I have given code like this in save button of visitor info form:

```
Private Sub BtnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
        Dim obj As New VisitorExitsign
        Dim vs As String = obj.txtvisitoridExit.Text
            Dim Visitorid As String = My.Forms.VisitorExitsign.txtvisitoridExit.Text
```

But I am always getting here txtvisitoridexit.text value null. Not getting the text value.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You need to lear that how you can pass value between two form

Answer (score 3):

You are creating new instance in every click event.

```
Dim obj As New VisitorExitsign
```

So the values are set in the new objects but not in existing object.

So actually you have to refer to existing object of VisitorExitsign.

**EDIT:**

For example:

You are creating form VisitorExitsign in some method.

**So whenever you are creating store its reference in some global variable.**

```
VisitorExitsign obj = new VisitorExitsign
```

**at the place where you are creating form**

then in click event use obj and assign text.

Comment: how i have to refer existing object?

Comment: @user3252014 In your code where you are creating the form take its reference..that's all.

Comment: sir you can see i am creating form refernce inside the button click event

Comment: Dim obj As  VisitorExitsign , i declared like this ,,and i try to cal txtbox value ,but still am not getting\

Comment: @user3252014 you are creating new VisitorExitsign in click event while you have to refer existing one...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57483/discussion-between-nirav-kamani-and-user3252014).

Comment: @user3252014 if you got the answer and if i was not wrong then you can accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to `My.Forms.VisitorExitSign.txtvisitoridExit.Text` you are referencing the form itself rather than an instance of the form, if that makes sense. So, you are trying to access the *default form* rather than one which the user has entered text into.

What you probably want to do is to change

```
Dim Visitorid As String = My.Forms.VisitorExitsign.txtvisitoridExit.Text`
```

into

```
Dim Visitorid As String = obj.txtvisitoridExit.Text
```

What that will do is make sure that the `Visitorid` is getting it's value from an *instance* of `VisitorExitSign`.

Comment: Is it perhaps because the on save you are creating a *new* instance of the `VisitorExitSign` rather than the existing one? (The new one won't appear until you do `Show()` or `ShowDialog()` on it.

You will need to use a previous reference when you first created the `VisitorExitSign` form.

So, if you make a global variable of type `VisitorExitSign` form, then when you create and show it, store it in that variable, then use that variable to get it's values.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   Handles Button1.Click

        Dim forms As FormCollection = Application.OpenForms
        For Each form As Form In forms
           If form.Name = "VisitorExitsign" Then
            Dim vs As String = CType(form, VisitorExitsign).txtvisitoridExit.Text
          End If
        Next

    End Sub
```

Suggesstion:

```
 frmVX = New VisitorExitsign 
frmVX.Location = New Point(781, 0) 
frmVX.MdiParent = Me 
frmVX.Show() 

frmVE = New VisitorInfo() 
frmVE.Location = New Point(0, 0) 
frmVE.MdiParent = Me 
frmVE.Tag=frmVX
frmVE.Show()
```

Button_Click Event

```
   Dim vs As String = CType(me.Tag, VisitorExitsign).txtvisitoridExit.Text
```

Comment: yeah. But OP want to exiting object and OP told that time 2 forms are in running so i tried like this @NiravKamani

Comment: so i can check wethar VisitorExitsign is opened? if opend then take value from that page..

Comment: this is working.but looping through all page my my application get slow right

Comment: ok which form is first shown in your code Show your form showing code @user3252014

Comment: sir i am calling this two form togethar.

Comment: in MDIparant form am calling this two from togethar:frmVX = New VisitorExitsign
        frmVX.Location = New Point(781, 0)
        frmVX.MdiParent = Me
        frmVX.Show()

        frmVE = New VisitorInfo()
        frmVE.Location = New Point(0, 0)
        frmVE.MdiParent = Me
        frmVE.Show()
like this

Comment: Its ok for you @user3252014

Comment: but getting error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: did you assign tag=formobject. that button is in VisitorInfo correct

Comment: `Dim forms As FormCollection = DirectCast(Application.OpenForms('FormCollection'), FormCollection)` would work correctly. No need to create loop

Answer (score 0):

*Hope this will works*

- create a `module`

  ```
  Module modTextValue
   Public _textVal As String
  End Module
  ```
- then goto `txtvisitoridexit`'s `LostFocus` event on your  form `vistirexitsign`

  ```
  Private Sub txtvisitoridexit_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.LostFocus
     _textVal = txtvisitoridexit.Text
  End Sub
  ```
- on `btnSave'click`

  ```
   Private Sub BtnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
     Dim str As String
     str = _textVal
   End Sub
  ```

Comment: where i have to creat module?

Comment: i am getting that textbox value,now my problem is aftergetting that value i am calling one of my function in vistorexit sign form ,but that time that textbox value getting null

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
 in button save update your code to :

```
  Private Sub BtnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
    Dim obj As New VisitorExitsign
    obj.ShowDialog()
    Dim vs As String = obj.txtvisitoridExit.Text
  End sub
```

when you close VisitorExitsign, the variable vs will take the value of obj.txtvisitoridExit