# value getting null while calling function from another form in windows form

Tags: vb.net, forms

i am working on windows form application.i have two froms
in MDIparant form i opening my two form together like this:

```
Public Class MDIParent1
    Dim frmVE As VisitorInfo
  Dim frmVX As VisitorExitsign 

Private Sub InvokeToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles InvokeToolStripMenuItem.Click

frmVX = New VisitorExitsign
        frmVX.Location = New Point(781, 0)
        frmVX.MdiParent = Me
        frmVX.Show()

        frmVE = New VisitorInfo()
        frmVE.Location = New Point(0, 0)
        frmVE.MdiParent = Me
        frmVE.Show()
```

now both forms are opend .i have one save button in Visitoinfo form .
also i have textbox in visitorexitsign form.name is txtvisitoridExit
while cliking save button i want to check wethar this textbox(txtvisitoridExit) contains any value,then i have to cal function in the VisitorExitsign form..so i wrote code like this:

```
Dim forms As FormCollection = Application.OpenForms
        For Each form As Form In forms
            If form.Name = "VisitorExitsign" Then
                Dim vs As String = CType(form, VisitorExitsign).txtvisitoridExit.Text
                VisitorExitsign.savebutton()
            End If
        Next
```

here am getting valu if vs .but 
while going VisitorExitsign page am getting this textbox value (txtvisitoridExit.Text) null.how come that value become null
how i can resolve this issue?

Comment: does your this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24800455/3682599) is solved ??

Comment: yes,,this another problem.

Comment: Nothing to do with that code. I'd suggest to resort your old friend Debugger. BTW no need to enumerate Application.OpenForms...

Comment: without that how i can get value from another form,

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti OP is much confused with this see his prev [quetsion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24800455/3682599)

Comment: @hector, yes...now I see!

Comment: When you create `VisitorInfo` in `InvokeToolStripMenuItem_Click` you may also pass a reference to newly created `VisitorExitsign` form. Moreover `txtvisitoridExit.Text` should be exposed by `VisitorExitsign` through a property (not directly making control instance public). Simplify your code and it'll easier to debug/understand (most of times solution IS simple, when it's getting too complicate then you know you're doing something wrong). Finally...`Text` property of a `TextBox` cannot be `null` `(Nothing`) but just empty.

Comment: i want to know how this getting nothing while go back to Visitorexitsign form

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:** You are calling a local variable in another scope(VisitorExitSign), this will result a null value.

**Solution:** Define a Public Static value for what you want to call in another form.

**Example:-**
In the first form

Public Static Dim textbox1 As String = txtvisitoridExit.Text

In the second from

Dim vs As String = CType(form, VisitorExitsign).txtvisitoridExit.Text

**Conclusion:** You will get the real value.

Comment: which form u mean first form??

Comment: As you wrote in your question.. you have two forms.
Define a static variable in your first form(VisitorExitsign).

Comment: Static variable? Really?